# Find two integers $a, b$ for given integer $c$, so that $c=a^2\pm b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Given a positive integer $c$: Find two other positive integers $a$ and $b$, so that $c=a^2 + b^2$ and/or $c=a^2 - b^2$.

I've already got a solution for any odd $c$:

$c = (x+1)^2 - x^2 = 2x + 1$

so $x=\dfrac{c-1}{2}$ and the solution is $c = \left(\dfrac{c+1}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\dfrac{c-1}{2}\right)^2$

Is there a way to solve this for any positive integer $c$? And if not, is it possible to describe all possible solutions and also describe all $c$ for which no solution exists?

Comment: @graydad: $x = \frac{c-1}{2}$ is an integer provided $c$ is odd.

Comment: @Krish Since the solutions $a$ and $b$ must be integers, my solution only works for odd numbers. Otherwise, $a$ and $b$ would not be integers.

Comment: There are no solutions for $c=6$ - a simple check exhausts the $a^2+b^2$ situation, for $a>3$, there is no other square in the interval $[a^2-6,a^2+6]$.

Comment: You can solve $c=a^2-b^2$ if and only if $c$ is odd or $c$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Try not to use "-" as a punctuation - too me a while to realize you didn't mean $c=6-a$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Whoops, that's amusing. I'll try to be more careful in the future.

Comment: The $a^2+b^2$ case is harder. If $c=xy^2$ for some square-free $x$, then $c=a^2+b^2$ has a solution if and only if $x>1$ has no prime divisor of the form $4k+3$.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that we can always write an odd number as a difference of two squares. We can easily show that a number $0 \pmod 4$ can be written as a difference of two squares by observing that

$$4n = (n + 1)^2 - (n - 1)^2.$$

Thus, we have the following proposition: You can always write $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as a difference of two squares *unless* it is of the form $4k + 2$, that is, $n\equiv 2 \pmod 4$. Let's prove it.

Let $n = a^2 - b^2$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
By [Square Mod 4](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_Modulo_4), both $a$ and $b$ are of the form $4k$ or $4k + 1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
There are 4 cases:
If $a \equiv b \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, then
$$a^2-b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$
and so $n$ is in the form $4k$.

If $a \equiv 0 \pmod 4, b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
$$a^2-b^2 \equiv - 1 \pmod 4 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$
and so $n$ is in the form $4k + 3$.

If $a \equiv 1 \pmod 4, b \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, then
$$a^2-b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$
and so $n$ is in the form $4k + 1$.

If $a \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
$$a^2-b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$
and so $n$ is in the form $4k$.

Thus, it is never the case that $a^2 - b^2 = 4k + 2$.